# Spring Mvc App get - HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I work with a `Spring Mvc app` and get HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]. The landing page is namely `index.jsp`,

[image]

and called from the controller method,

```
@Controller
public class BitcoinWalletController {

   @RequestMapping("/")
   public String showBitcoinWallet() {

      return "index";
   }
}
```

In the `index.jsp` page, send money button is initially disabled,

```
<div class="buttons_box">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg active" <%= canSendMoney ? "" : "disabled='true'"%>
                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Send money
            </button>
        </div>
```

and only be active if the synchronization is completed and `boolean canSendMoney` returns `true`.

If the button is active, the code handles the `POST` operation is provided,

```
        <%--modal contents here--%>
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="model-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times!</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Send Money</h4>
            </div>

            <form id="send-form" class="form-horizontal" action="sendMoney.jsp" method="POST">

                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="amount" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Send</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <input id="amount" name="amount" class="form-control" value="0">
                        </div>
                        <div class="btc-col">
                            <span>BTC</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="address" class="col-sm-2 control-label">to</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input id="address" name="address" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
```

The `sendMoney.jsp` code is provided below,

```
<body>
<%
    String amount = request.getParameter("amount").trim();
    String address = request.getParameter("address").trim();

    WalletSendMoneyController.getSendMoneyController().send(address, amount);

    // New location to be redirected
    String site = new String("/");
    response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
    response.setHeader("Location", site);
%>
</body>
```

When I put all the required and correct infos and press the button, It should return to the original page- `index.jsp`. Instead, I get the error, `HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]`,

[image]

I currently don't have any handle for the address `http://localhost:8080/sendMoney.jsp`. Because, if the `POST` submission is correct, I would like to redirect to the  "/".

I have the `jsps` in the `WEB-INF` folder in the project directory,

[image]

The `jsps` location provided in the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file,

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
```

The `we.xml` knows where the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` is located,

```
<servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>dispatcher</display-name>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

How to solve the issue? Thanks.

Comment: POST request suppose to have a method in Controller. `/sendMoney.jsp` is actually trying to find map to controllers but not found anything. So it throws 404

Comment: What would be the `RequestMapping ` and what it should return in the first place? I only need the page `sendMoney.jsp`  as pop-up after pressing the `send money` button and then, to redirected to the `index.jsp` (of the address `http://localhost:8080)

Comment: better make a controller to receive POST request. Do the `..money.send()` along with other things in that controller. Then redirect to `/` from the controller.

Comment: Please provide sample code to make understand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Mvc get HTTP Status \[404\] – \[Not Found\] after the submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539181/spring-mvc-get-http-status-404-not-found-after-the-submission)

Comment: Yes, I can't delete it now. Let's keep it as it is.

Comment: @Are I have posted answer for you in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your code showing: You are actually trying to submit form to `sendMoney.jsp` which is not exist(might be, cause i can't see your whole project). Though you need to submit the form to a controller with a `ModelAttribute` which you need to create.

The following things you have to do for POST to controller from form.

**Make a class for form fields**

```
public class Data {
    private String address;
    private String amount;

    public Data() {
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

**Bind a new Data object in GET controller where you load the form in HTML**

```
@RequestMapping("/")
 public String showBitcoinWallet() {
    model.addAttribute("data", new Data());
    return "index";
}
```

**The following form will be in your `index.jsp` page, Where `/send` is the controller's mapping where to POST the form**

```
<form:form id="send-form" modelAttribute="data" class="form-horizontal" action="/send" method="POST"> 

    <div class="modal-body">

        <spring:bind path="amount">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="amount" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Send</label>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <form:input path="amount" id="amount" name="amount" class="form-control" value="0"></form:input>
            </div>
            <div class="btc-col">
                <span>BTC</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        </spring:bind>

        <spring:bind path="address">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address" class="col-sm-2 control-label">to</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <form:input path="address" id="address" name="address" class="form-control"></form:input>
            </div>
        </div>
        </spring:bind>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
    </div>

</form:form>
```

**Following controller for `/send` POST**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/send", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sendMoney(Data data) {
        //here will be your code for send money and whatever you have to do..
        ...send(data.getAddress(), data.getAmount()); 
        return "redirect:/"; //here will the location where you want to redirect
    }
```

Comment: The `sendMoney.jsp` is indeed inside the project.

Comment: That is a jsp file. Not controller mapping.

Answer (score 1):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Have you defined this in your spring-config.xml file ??