# Spring Mvc get HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found] after the submission

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I work with Spring Mvc and have the controller returns the `index.jsp` page,

```
@Controller
public class BitcoinWalletController {

   @RequestMapping("/")
   public String showBitcoinWallet() {

      return "index";
   }
}
```

This is the `index.jsp` page,

[image]

The code to handle the submission operation (inside the `index.jsp`),

```
    <form id="send-form" class="form-horizontal" action="sendMoney.jsp" method="POST">

        <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="amount" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Send</label>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input id="amount" name="amount" class="form-control" value="0">
                </div>
                <div class="btc-col">
                    <span>BTC</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="address" class="col-sm-2 control-label">to</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input id="address" name="address" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
        </div>

    </form>
```

The code for the `sendMoney.jsp` provided,

```
<%@ page import="com.puut.bitcoin.WalletSendMoneyController" %>

<html>
<body>
<%
    String amount = request.getParameter("amount").trim();
    String address = request.getParameter("address").trim();

    WalletSendMoneyController.getSendMoneyController().send(address, amount);

    // New location to be redirected
    String site = new String("/");
    response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
    response.setHeader("Location", site);
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect that after the submission of the pop-up, I should redirected to the original `index.jsp` page.

[image]

Instead, I get the following error,

```
HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found] after the submission
```

[image]

The app structure,

[image]

The jsps location provided in the dispatcher-servlet.xml file,

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
```

The web.xml knows where the dispatcher-servlet.xml is located,

```
<servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>dispatcher</display-name>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I have no other `mapping` then the `@RequestMapping("/")`.

If I remove the `action="sendMoney.jsp"` from the `index.jsp` and have another controller with the `POST` method as suggested, I get the following stack of errors,

```
Type Exception Report

Message Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.MediaType.compareTo(Lorg/springframework/http/MediaType;)I

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.MediaType.compareTo(Lorg/springframework/http/MediaType;)I
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1259)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

How to solve the issue? Thanks.

Comment: move sendMoney.jsp codes into new controller with @RequestMapping("/sendMoney"), and redirect main page in it. Set html form action="sendMoney" to invoke it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please to try handle the Post Request from controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView PostBitcoinWallet(@RequestParam String amount,@RequestParam String address) {

      ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
        modelMap.put("amount", amount);
        modelMap.put("address", address);

      return new ModelAndView("sendMoney",modelMap);
   }
```

and on sendMoney.jsp you can get the parametres puted on the modelMap :

```
<label>Amount</label> <span>${amount}</span>
<label>Adress</label> <span>${address}</span>
```

For best practices  do not include java code on jsp file

Comment: I don't want to go in the  `URL localhost:8080/sendMoney.jsp`. The `send money` button should pop-up the submit option provided and after the `send` it should go in the original page. How can I work it out?

Comment: you can return a redirect on the Post Request mapping like this : `return "redirect:http://www.google.com"`

Comment: I put your code in place. It still doesn't work out though.

Comment: can you please share the new controller for more investigation

Comment: I have only one controller besides the one you have provided for handling the `POST` request.

Comment: i just test a simple controller and it work the redirection : `@RequestMapping(value = { "/"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String defaultPage() {
  
  return "redirect:http://www.google.com";

 }`

Comment: Same happens. When I press the `send` submission button, I always get `404 error`

Comment: are you removing `action="sendMoney.jsp"` from you form?if not please to remove it

Comment: I get the error `NoSuchMethodError ` Have a look in the updated question. You may start it as an answer and modify as necessary.